# Вопрос о реализации конструктора класса

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

Помогите понять данный вид записи конструктора.

```
class_name (char * n = 0, int p = 0, int g = 0) : name (initname (n)) {
    phone = p;
    group = g;
};
```

То есть вопрос в том, что в такой записи обозначает текст в скобках, что после двоеточия, что тот, что в фигурных скобках.

И в чем отличия от конструктора вида:

```
class_name () {
    ...
}
```

или

```
class_name ( ... ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: "member initializer lists"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class_name (char * n = 0, int p = 0, int g = 0) : name (initname (n)) {
    phone = p;
    group = g;
};
```

Означает:

- `char * n, int p, int g`  по умолчанию имеют  нулевое значение.
- `name` конструируется со значением `initname (n)`.
  Также в списке инициализатора могут инициализироваться члены ссыльки и константные члены, для инициализации которых нет другого способа.
- члены `phone` и `group` конструируются со значением по умолчанию(для `int` это
  ноль) а потом им присваивается значение `p` и `g` соответственно (в теле конструктора). В теле конструктора могут быть осуществлены любые возможные(допустимые для сохранения инварианта) операции таким же успехом, как и в теле любой функции.

: Еще обратите внимание на правильное замечание от Croessmah.

Различие последных двух конструкторов в наличии аргументов и отсутствие аргументов.  Первый конструктор (конструктор по умолчанию) позволяет создать обьект без аргументов, второй позволяет создать обьект с соответствующими аргументами.

- Если нет первого конструктора и есть второй:

  все аргументы имеют значения по умолчанию (как в вашем случаи),  то возможно создать `class_name obj`;

в обратном случаи обьект можно создать только с соответствующими

аргументами   `class_name obj(x, ...)`

Comment: Для int всё может быть сложнее. ```new class_name()``` - инициализируются нулями, ```new class_name``` - инициализируются мусором.

Comment: @Croessmah, о каких сложностях речь? Сразу говорите, чтоб люди были в курсе. Теперь другое дело. Хорошее замечание

Comment: Случайно отправил не дописав :)

Answer (score 0):

**В круглых скобках** объявляются принимаемые конструктором параметры.

**После двоеточие** можно сконструировать члены класса, например, константу.

**В фигурных скобках** просто идёт любой код.

Различие последних 2-х конструкторов - это с-шный способ принимать множество параметров (любое множество). Не рекомендуется.